# Connection String For Local and Remote MSSQL SQL Insert Into

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, connection-string

I have this code that will insert into the data from one table to another. The problem, is I am now trying to insert into a table from remote mssql server to my local mssql server. How will be the sql script for it, using VB.net?

I am presently getting an error:

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

This is my code as of the moment:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0


 Dim myConnectionString = "Data Source=(IP Address),1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password;"

   Dim myconnectionstring2 = "Data Source= PC-Name;Initial Catalog=dbase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"

   'Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)





   Dim myQuery As String = "INSERT INTO dbase.dbo.tbltransactions1 SELECT * FROM dbase.dbo.tbltransactions1"

   'Dim myQuery As String = "insert INTO (table)"

   'select

   'from LinkedserverName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName"

   Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection, myConnection2)



   Try

       myConnection.Open()

       rowsAffected = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

   Catch ex As Exception

       MsgBox(" ")

   Finally

       myConnection.Close()

   End Try



   Label1.Text = rowsAffected.ToString()
End Sub
```

*The connection string that has an IP address is the server I want to connect while the other one is the connection string for my local server..

Comment: Do you get a error message?

Comment: Yup.. I do the error Message is: network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot would be a `Linked Server` to your local server pointing to the remote server.

Another way to do it is fetch the remote data localy in a `DataTable` for example, and then push it to your local DB from the `DataTable`.

Currently you are ordering your local sql to communicate with the remote server. This is not going to happen without setting up a `Linked Server`.

In order to setup a `Linked Server`:

1. Open `SSMS` and connect to your local server.
2. Expand your server node.
3. Expand `Server Objects`.
4. `Right Click` on `Linked Servers`.
5. Select `New Linked Server`
6. Type the IP of the remote server on the `Server Name`
7. Select `SQL Server`
8. Add a Login mapping in the `Security` tab. You will have to provide credentials for the remote server.
9. In the `Local Login` column add the user name you use to connect to the `Local Server`.
10. Leave the `Impersonate` col unchecked if the credentials to the remote server are different than the ones in the Local server (which should be the case)
11. Enter the user name and the password that you would use to login to the `Remote Server` under `Remote User` and `Remote Password` respectively.
12. For security reasons i would select the `Not Be Made` in the radio group on the bottom of that tab.

Then you will be able to run queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM [RemoteServerIP].[RemoteServerDB].[RemoteServerSchema].[RemoteServerTable]
```

Comment: Thank Sir.. Gonna Try this!

Comment: Sir Follow up question regarding to login mapping in the Security tab.. What login should I use? my login in the local server?

Comment: thanks for the reply Sir.. really appreciate it.. I just want to clarify sir If you don't mind about the remote user and remote password.. this is the one that I login in SQL or the one in RDP? Thanks..

Comment: It is the ones you use in SQL Server Management Studio in the remote server. That means, 1. You login with RDP to the remote Windows Server and then you Login to SSMS in the Remote Windows Server. You need the second credentials.

Comment: Now ... there are several reasons for this. I would suggest checking the configuration of the remote SQL Server. Does it accept remote connections? Does it listen to the default port? I am not really suitable for troubleshooting this as i am no DBA, but i would suggest you checked some links in google or even asking a new question here. I found some links if you wish: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/335874/A-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occur

Comment: 1st...You are not annoying :) We all have been there where we are stuck and do not know what to do. 2nd... Try changing '61.28.150.140' to [61.28.150.140]. 3rd... For your security i would avoid posting sensitive data such as IPs, PC names etc. in a public site.